# Draw non full matrix of random numbers

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

I am doing a Monte-Carlo simulation, where each repetition requires the sum or product of a random number of random variables. My problem is how to do this efficiently as the entire simulation should be as vectorized as possible.

For example, say we want to take the sum of `5`, `10` and `3` random numbers, represented by the vector `len = [5;10;3]`. Then what I am currently doing is drawing a full matrix of random numbers:

```
A = randn(length(len),max(len));
```

Creating a mask of the non-needed numbers:

```
lenlen = repmat(len,1,max(len));
idx = repmat(1:max(len),length(len),1);
mask = idx>lenlen;
```

and then I can "pad", the matrix as I am interested in the sum the padding have to be zero (for the case with the product the padding had to be 1)

```
A(mask)=0;
```

To obtain:

```
A =

1.7708   -1.4609   -1.5637   -0.0340    0.9796         0         0         0         0         0
1.8034   -1.5467    0.3938    0.8777    0.6813    1.0594   -0.3469    1.7472   -0.4697   -0.3635
1.5937   -0.1170    1.5629         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Whereafter I can sum them together

```
B = sum(A,2);
```

However, I find it rather superfluous that I have to draw too many random numbers and then throw them away. In the real case, I need in the range of hundred thousands of repetitions and the vector `len` might vary a lot, i.e. it can easily be that I have to draw twice or three times the number of random numbers than of what is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the exact amount of random numbers required, create a grouping variable with [`repelem`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html), and compute the sum of each group using [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
len = [5; 10; 3];
B = accumarray(repelem(1:numel(len), len).', randn(sum(len),1));
```

Comment: This looks so neat, I thought it would be rapid... takes ~3x longer than my `arrayfun` method though using my [rough and ready benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49979866/3978545) in R2017b. Some quick tests show that using `randn` once for a large input size is slower than equivalent output from many smaller calls... probably due to memory consumption. i.e. `randn(1e7,1)` vs `for ii=1:1e3; randn(1e4,1); end`

Comment: @Wolfie That makes a lot of sense. I've seen my computer become unresponsive in the past when trying to generate large arrays with `rand`or `randn` (even if they would fit in RAM)

Comment: I wonder how hardware dependent the difference is, and therefore whether there's a consistent optimum crossover for many small calls vs one large call... A question for another day perhaps!

Comment: @Wolfie [Apparently](https://gist.github.com/lmendo/eb3bcca0a92942a15c9ba23cf91232f4), the optimum size is very small, of the order of `10`. On the other hand, replacing `rand` by `ones` produces the same behaviour. So it seems to be mainly a memory thing, yes

Comment: Thanks for the code, I can verify similar results on R2017b and R2015b on my machine. The long-dormant statistician in me is wondering how the random sampling is different in each case too, but I guess we should assume the MathWorks folks made sure it would be independent either way.

Comment: @Wolfie If I understand correctly, that dormant statistician can rest assured :-) `rng(123); x = rand(1,2e3); rng(123); y = rand(1,1e3); y = [y rand(1,1e3)]; isequal(x, y)`

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `arrayfun` or a loop. You say "efficient" and "vectorized" in the same breath, but they are not necessarily the same thing - since the new(ish) JIT compiler, loops are pretty fast in MATLAB. `arrayfun` is basically a loop in disguise, but means you could create `B` like so:

```
len = [5;10;3];
B = arrayfun( @(x) sum( randn(x,1) ), len );
```

For each element in `len`, this creates a vector of length `len(i)` and takes the sum. The output is an array with one value for each value in `len`.

This will certainly be a lot more memory friendly for large values and largely different values within `len`. It may therefore be quicker, your mileage may vary but it cuts out a lot of the operations you're doing.

You mention wanting to take the product sometimes, in which case use `prod` in place of `sum`.

---

Edit: rough and ready benchmark to compare `arrayfun` and a loop...

```
len = randi([1e3, 1e7], 100, 1);

tic; 
B = arrayfun( @(x) sum( randn(x,1) ), len ); 
toc % ~8.77 seconds

tic; 
out=zeros(size(len)); 
for ii = 1:numel(len)
    out(ii) = sum(randn(len(ii),1));
end
toc % ~8.80 seconds
```

The "advantage" of the loop over `arrayfun` is you can pre-generate all of the random numbers in one go, then index. This isn't necesarryily quicker because you're addressing much bigger chunks of memory, and the call to `randn` is the main bottleneck anyway!

```
tic; 
out = zeros(size(len)); 
rnd = randn(sum(len),1);
idx = [0; cumsum(len)]; % note: cumsum is very quick (~0.001sec here) so negligible
for ii = 1:numel(len)
    out(ii) = sum(rnd(idx(ii)+1:idx(ii+1)),1);
end
toc % ~10.2 sec! Slower because of massive call to randn and the indexing into large array.
```

As stated at the top, `arrayfun` and looping are basically the same under the hood, so no reason to expect a big time difference.

Comment: I agree that the new JIT compiler heavily improves on loop, but a comparable vectorised solution is still faster. Won't an explicit for-loop not always be faster than using `arrayfun`?

Comment: It is faster if it exists, your existing solution is vectorised on every line, but has more operations on larger arrays so will likely be slower... I just ran a small benchmark (edited into answer) which shows the loop and `arrayfun` are comparable - as I say they're basically the same under the hood.

Comment: @Nicky I've added a slight variation to the benchmark which may interest you.

Comment: That is actually quite interesting. I would have imagined that the last would have been the fastest.

Comment: @Nicky thanks, I'm curious why you accepted/preferred Luis' answer? It's of comparable length to my `arrayfun` solution and [slower for large `len`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979585/draw-non-full-matrix-of-random-numbers/49979866#comment86981763_49982336)... Of course use whatever is best for your application, I just wondered if there was some advantage you found with that solution?

Comment: Tbh, I was really in doubt of which one to accept, I really liked both of your suggestions. The minute difference was that on the array `len = randi(1e2,1e6,1);`, which best resembles my case he was slightly faster, whereas your method is faster for larger values, i.e. values in the range `[1e3,1e5]`, as shown on your timings.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of multiple random numbers drawn from a specific distribution is also a random number with a (different) specific distribution. Therefore you can just cut the middleman and draw directly from the latter distribution.

In your case you are summing 3, 10 and 5 numbers drawn from a N(0,1) distribution. As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables), the resulting distributions therefore are N(0,3), N(0,10) and N(0,5). [This page](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-numbers-with-specific-mean-and-variance.html) explains how you can draw from non-standard normal distributions in Matlab. As such, we can in this case generate those numbers with `randn(3,1).*sqrt([5; 10; 3])`.

In case you would want 1000 triples, you could then use

```
randn(3,1000).*sqrt([5; 10; 3])
```

or pre Matlab2016b

```
bsxfun(@times, randn(3,1000), sqrt([5; 10; 3]))
```

which is of course very fast.

Different distributions have different summation rules, but as long as you are not summing up numbers drawn from different distributions the rules are usually quite simple and found quickly with google.

Comment: Unfortunately, my distribution is not simple, it is the sum of correlated lognormal numbers. I just used the normal distribution in the example for ease. Though, you have an important point.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a combination of `cumsum` and `diff`. The plan is:

1. Create all the random numbers in a single call to `randn` up front
2. Then, use `cumsum` to produce a vector of cumulative summations
3. Use `cumsum` on the list of number-of-samples-per-result to work out where to read out the results
4. We also need `diff` to correct for the prior summations.

Note that this method might lose accuracy if you weren't using `randn` for the random samples, as `cumsum` would then build up arithmetic rounding errors.

```
% We want 100 sums of random numbers
numSamples = 100;
% Here's where we define how many random samples contribute to each sum
numRandsPerSample = randi(5, 1, numSamples);

% Let's make all the random numbers in one call
allRands = randn(1, sum(numRandsPerSample));

% Use CUMSUM to build up a cumulative sum of the whole of allRands. We also
% need a leading 0 for the first sum.
allRandsCS = [0, cumsum(allRands)];
% Use CUMSUM again to pick out the places we need to pick from 
% allRandsCS
endIdxs = 1 + [0, cumsum(numRandsPerSample)];
% Use DIFF to subtract the prior sums from the result.
result = diff(allRandsCS(endIdxs))
```